# Dagger2 Android subcomponent injection in nonAndroid classes

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

Learning Dagger2 and maybe going off the rails here. I have a class - MapRoute that may or may not be needed in a Fragment. If MapRoute is needed, I want to create it and when the MapRoute is instantiated I want to inject it with dependencies created at the application level. I am also using Builder pattern to populate MapRouter.

Perhaps the generic question is when you are in nonAndroid classes (not Activity/Fragment/...) how can you inject dependencies from above? How to you construct the nonAndroid injector in place of AndroidInjection.inject(this)?

So my fragment is:

```
public class ActivityMapFragment extends DaggerFragment ... {

 @Inject
    MapRoute.Builder mapRouteBuilder;

 private void plotRouteForMap(Cursor csr){
    MapRoute.Builder builder = new MapRoute.Builder();
    builder.setSupportMapFragment(supportMapFragment)
            .setLocationExerciseRecord(ler)
            .setMapType(mapType)
            .setUseCurrentLocationLabel(useCurrentLocationLabel)
            .setCursor(csr)
            .setTitle(activityTitle)
            .setActivityPhotosCallback(this);
    mapRoute = builder.build();
    mapRoute.plotGpsRoute();
}
...
```

MapRoute is: **(Edit)** added Builder code snippet

```
public class MapRoute ... {

@Inject
public DisplayUnits displayUnits;   <<< Created at app level

@Inject
public PhotoUtils photoUtils;       <<<< Create at app level

 public MapRoute() {
    // Use subcomponent builder
    MapRouteSubcomponent component = 
    DaggerMapRouteSubComponent.builder().build();   <<< Want to do this
    component.inject(this);
}

 public static class Builder {
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    LocationExerciseRecord ler;
    boolean useCurrentLocationLabel;
    int mapType;
    Cursor cursor;
    ActivityPhotosCallback activityPhotosCallback;
    String title;

    @Inject
    public Builder() {
    }
      public Builder setSupportMapFragment(SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment){
        this.supportMapFragment = supportMapFragment;
        return this;
    }
 ....
```

MapRouteSubcomponent best guess:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {MapRouteModule.class, ApplicationModule.class})
```

public interface MapRouteSubcomponent {

```
// allow to inject into our MapRoute class
void inject(MapRoute mapRoute);


@Subcomponent.Builder
interface Builder extends SubComponentBuilder<MapRouteSubcomponent> {
    Builder mapRouteModule(MapRouteModule mapRouteModule);
}


@Module
public class MapRouteModule {
    // What to put here?
}
```

And finally a subcomponent builder:

```
 // from https://github.com/Zorail/SubComponent/blob/master/app/src/main/java/zorail/rohan/com/subcomponent/SubComponentBuilder.java
public interface SubComponentBuilder<V> {
    V build();
}
```

At this point I am at a stand on where to go from here.